# I want to make an online App that send and recive data

Tags: c#

i try to make an app that help the Students and teachers with learning. The app has allready Offline mode, but what i wanna do is give acces to the teacher throw a code that anly he knows and choose from a list of question witch question he wants the students to recive for a test. So want i'm asking is how kann i make the app having acces to the internet and when the teacher is done choosing the question to send it to all of the students? And then after the students are done with the test, sending the data back to the teacher. I've never done an Online App and if you have a good tutorial on youtube about that plese give me the link. Any idee is welcomed. Thank you.

Edit: What i forgot to say is that i m verry confortable with Unity and i really like working with it. So i've started this project in Unity with the ideea of making a game that helps students with learning and evolved. Is Unity that bad for this kind of Apps? I read some forums that say that making Windows Apps in Unity it's actually not that bad. What do you guys think?

Comment: It is better to have a database with multiple tables.  Some tables teacher has read/write and students only read.  Other tables both students and teacher have read/write.  Teacher writes to database which question student can read.  Then student app reads from database.

Answer (score 0):

Nice goal. you have a lot to do, start with learning client/server applications -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI

Then you need to build a database to hold all the questions and students.

You can also make it more automatic by inserting the answers in advance and letting the software to grade the test without the need of the teacher to do so.

It is a good goal for learning to develope! good luck!